# Is there a way to add the same item val="4" to each object of array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, angularjs

Is there a way to add the same item val="4" to each object of array in JavaScript?

Let's say there is

```
var arr = [{"num":"111"},{"ttt":"123","rss":"456"},...];
```

I'd like to get

```
arr2 = [{"num":"111", "val":"4"},{"ttt":"123", "rss":"456", "val":"4"},...];
```

Is it possible to make in one line with kind of `.push()` to array or something similar?

Comment: I removed the "best" from your title and text because I'm guessing you're look for "a way" rather than some opinionated "best" way, which would be off topic for SO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `.map` function will work wonders for you!

```
var arr2 = arr.map(function(item) {
    item.val = 4;
    return item;
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 4):

While tymeJV's solution works, I find it slightly confusing as `.map()` is meant to return new objects and `.forEach()` is meant for doing side effects.

If you wanted to mutate the original array then this makes more sense IMO

```
arr.forEach(function(item) {
  item.val = 4;
})
```

If you wanted to return a new array and leave the old one untouched then this should work

```
var arr2 = arr.map(function(item) {
  return Object.assign({}, item, {val: 4})
})
```

Or if you're targeting a browser that allows arrow functions:

```
var arr2 = arr.map(item => Object.assign({}, item, {val: 4}) );
```

Answer (score 4):

(Very similar to @tymeJV)

You could actually use `.forEach(..)` instead of `.map`. You could technically do the achieve the same thing with both but there is a subtle stylistic (cross-language) difference. Use `map` when you are literally converting each object from one form to another **without modifying the original object**. If you want to modify the original object, you'd *typically* use `forEach` instead.

```
//Makes changes in place (original array is modified.
arr.forEach(function(item) {
    item.val = 4;
});

//To ensure the original object `arr` isn't modified
arr2 = arr.map(function(item) {
    var cloneObj = clone(item); //For clone see link below
    cloneObj.val = 4;
    return cloneObj;
});
```

[Implementations of clone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/most-elegant-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object)